# Python: Calling functions from the same module

Tags: python, module

I am designing a module, say `mymodule.py` and I write the code for the module as follows:

```
def charCount(my_string, my_char):
    a = my_string.count(my_char) 
    return a

def aCount(my_string):
    a = charCount(my_string, 'a')
    return a
```

Inside Python shell, I use the following command:

```
import mymodule as mm
```

and then,

```
mString = 'ghghghghgaaaaa'
```

and then

```
a = mm.aCount(mString)
```

It is seen that there is an error. Apparently, the function is not able to be called from the same module. How can this be avoided?

Comment: It works perfectly. Please check the missing colon after aCount

Comment: Note that your functions do nothing.

Comment: What @timgeb is correct, please check that also, you're not returning anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put return statement in both the functions and it would work fine.
Try this:

```
def charCount(my_string, my_char):
    a = my_string.count(my_char)
    return a

def aCount(my_string):
    a = charCount(my_string, 'a')
    return a
```